# T-SQL Dynamic Pivot on different and multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

Table Student:

```
Studid      StuName     
=========================
1           'Marco Polo'
2           'Leroy Jenkins'
```

Table Subjects:

```
Subid      SubName     
===================
1           English
2           French
3           German
4           Math
5           Physics
```

Table Grades

```
Stuid      Subid          Grade1            Grade2
==================================================
1           1                10               6    
1           2                9                7    
2           1                8                4    
2           4                7                9    
2           5                6                10
```

I would like to achieve 2 tables:
Table1:

```
StuName      English 1      English 2      French 1       French 2
==================================================================
'Marco Polo'     10             6              9              7
```

Table1:

```
StuName      English 1      English 2      Math 1       Math 2      Physics 1       Physics 2
==================================================================
'Leroy Jenkins'    8             4              7              9    6              10
```

Comment: The problem is that Leroy is going to rush in before you've even finished writing your query.

Comment: It's not very clear as to what your expected result should be. Also, could you provide what you've tried so far?

Comment: I didn't try anything, I have no clue because notice that the number of fields is one time 5 and another is 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example the id on `Student` is `StudId` and in `Grades` it is `StuId`. This may or may not be a typo, but I left it as posted.

You need to `unpivot` the subject+gradenumber (I use the `cross apply(values... )` method to `unpivot` in the code below but a `union all` or `unpivot()` version would work as well), and then pivot.

Since you only want to return columns specific to each student, you use a filter on the column list generation and in the inner query of the `pivot` and pass that parameter to `sp_executesql` for the execution of the generated code.

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max), @sql nvarchar(max), @StuId int;
set @StuId = 2;
set @cols = stuff((
    select ', ' + quotename(sub.subName+'1')+', '+ quotename(sub.subName+'2')
    from Grades g
      inner join Student stu
        on g.StuId = stu.StudId
      inner join Subjects sub 
        on g.SubId = sub.SubId
    where stu.StudId = @StuId
    order by 1
    for xml path (''), type).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
    ,1,2,'');
set @sql = '
    select StuName, '+ @cols +'
    from (
      select stu.StuName, u.SubName, u.Grade
      from Grades g
        inner join Student stu
          on g.StuId = stu.StudId
        inner join Subjects sub 
          on g.SubId = sub.SubId
        cross apply (values 
            (sub.SubName+''1'', g.Grade1)
          , (sub.SubName+''2'', g.Grade2)
          )u (SubName,Grade) 
      where stu.StudId = @StuId
      ) as t
    pivot (sum(Grade) for SubName in (' + @cols +')) p';

select CodeGenerated = @sql;
exec sp_executesql @sql ,N'@StuId int', @StuId;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/DCLY81531

returns `CodeGenerated`:

```
select StuName, [English1], [English2], [Math1], [Math2], [Physics1], [Physics2]
    from (
      select stu.StuName, u.SubName, u.Grade
      from Grades g
        inner join Student stu
          on g.StuId = stu.StudId
        inner join Subjects sub 
          on g.SubId = sub.SubId
        cross apply (values 
            (sub.SubName+'1', g.Grade1)
          , (sub.SubName+'2', g.Grade2)
          )u (SubName,Grade) 
      where stu.StudId = @StuId
      ) as t
    pivot (sum(Grade) for SubName in ([English1], [English2], [Math1], [Math2], [Physics1], [Physics2])) p
```

for `@StuId = 2` returns:

```
+---------------+----------+----------+-------+-------+----------+----------+
|    StuName    | English1 | English2 | Math1 | Math2 | Physics1 | Physics2 |
+---------------+----------+----------+-------+-------+----------+----------+
| Leroy Jenkins |        8 |        4 |     7 |     9 |        6 |       10 |
+---------------+----------+----------+-------+-------+----------+----------+
```

for `@StuId = 1` returns:

```
+------------+----------+----------+---------+---------+
|  StuName   | English1 | English2 | French1 | French2 |
+------------+----------+----------+---------+---------+
| Marco Polo |       10 |        6 |       9 |       7 |
+------------+----------+----------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Studid is a typo, it's Stuid.
Thank you for the answer, marked as the correct one.